# Printing a tree with brackets C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, printing, tree

I have code as followed

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


struct Node{
    std::string name;
    Node * parent;
    std::vector<Node *> children;
};

void storeOutput(Node * nod, std::string &str)
{
    str += nod->name;
    str += "{";
    if(nod->children.size() > 0){
        for(auto &n : nod->children){
            storeOutput(n, str);
            str += "}";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
  // Create nodes
  Node * root = new Node();
  root->name = "root";
  Node * child1 = new Node();
  child1->name = "child1";
  Node * child2 = new Node();
  child2->name = "child2";
  Node * child3 = new Node();
  child3->name = "child1.1";

  // Set parents
  root->parent = nullptr;
  child1->parent = root;
  child2->parent = root;
  child3->parent = child1;

  // Assign children
  std::vector<Node *> rootChildren;
  rootChildren.push_back(child1);
  rootChildren.push_back(child2);
  root->children = rootChildren;
  std::vector<Node *> child1Children;
  child1Children.push_back(child3);
  child1->children = child1Children;

  // Print nodes
  std::string output;
  Node * node = root;
  storeOutput(node, output);
  std::cout << output;

}
```

How would I print out this tree starting from the root node into a string the following format:

```
root 
{ 
    child1
    { 
        child1.1 
        { 
        } 
    } 
    child2 
    { 
    } 
}
```

I understand that the methods for doing this relate to tree traversal of the stored nodes, but I am unsure of how to implement these.

I now am printing out the list, but its missing an ending parenthesis.

```
root{child1{child1.1{}}child2{}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Yunnosch I would like to know how to print out the tree in the format

Comment: Questions which basically ask "What is the code which achieves my requirements?" are too broad.

Comment: You were able to write your example by hand, so you must have an algorithm; what is it?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] of your best code. Whatever you have. You do have something which at least prints all entries in the vector and only lack proper indentation, don't you? Show that. Then show the output and describe what you do not like about it. If you do not even have something like this, then please understand that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: My first coding attempt for this would use a recursive function. From the information you give (especially the total absence of any own programming attempt) I cannot tell whether that is a tool you already have mastered.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have added a complete example, but I don't know how to traverse the data structure, so have not included that code.

Comment: According to "And these are stored in a vector like below `root->children = rootChildren; vector<Node *> myNodes;`" all are stored in a vector. (Even if you recently deleted that information from the question.) It would not require any traversing. Please show your code for outputting everything in the vector.

Comment: You have shown code and it provides a foundation for this discussion. Good. However, you still did not demonstrate any own effort. Please at leat go the very first step. And the more easy little steps you go yourself, i.e. the more own effort you demonstrate, the more the people here will feel inclined to help you.

Comment: For actually traversing a tree (you are right, it will of course become necessary) using recursive functions will be pretty much unavoidable. Consider stating (ideally demonstrating) that you know about them and are able to create one. E.g. write one which outputs a node and then calls itself for all children. If you apply that to the root node you are almost done with traversing. The rest is just some indentation magic.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for the help. I have updated my answer with your help. I'm missing a closing parenthesis, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I rewrite your output function. It looks rough but it work

```
 void storeOutput (Node * nod, std::string & str, int p)
{
  p++;

  for (int x = 0; x < p; x++)
  {
    str += "  ";
  }

  str += nod->name;



  str += "\n";

  for (int x = 0; x < p; x++)
  {
    str += "  ";
  }

  str += "{ \n";
  if (nod->children.size () > 0)
    {
    for (auto & n:nod->children)
    {
      storeOutput (n, str, p);

      for (int x = 0; x < p + 1; x++)
      {
        str += "  ";
      }

      str += "} \n";

      p--;
    }
    }
}
```